# insert into statement to select records from access (mdb) file

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

Is there a way that I can use access(mdb) file in sql(t-sql) insert into statement?

I have a client table in my sql CE and I have same like table in another access database, i want to import records from some column of this access table into my sql CE. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OPENROWSET and friends. To read Access files, see example B: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx